# How do I get selected list values in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am passing my Visualforce page the following code to have users select an employment website to post a position on:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Position__c" extensions="PositionExtension">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Create New Position">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >

    <apex:commandButton title="Save" value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
    <apex:commandButton title="Edit" value="Edit" action="{!edit}"/>
    <apex:commandButton title="Cancel" value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>

    </apex:pageBlockButtons>


<apex:pageBlockSection columns="3" title="Basic Information"> 

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

    Position Title
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.name}" required="true"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    Record Type
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.recordtypeId}" required="true"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    Open Date

    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Open_Date__c}"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

    Close Date

    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Close_Date__c}"/>

    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

   Hire By

   <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Hire_By__c}"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >     

    Job Type
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Type__c}" required="true"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

    Location
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Location__c}" required="true"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

    Travel Required?

    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Travel_Required__c}" required="false"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >     

    Status
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Status__c}" required="true"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >     

    Functional Area
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Functional_Area__c}" required="true"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >     

    Job Level
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Job_Level__c}" required="true"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

    Job Description
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Job_Description__c}" required="true"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

    Responsibilities
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Responsibilities__c}" 
required="true"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<br></br>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

    Min Pay
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Min_Pay__c}" 
required="true"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

    Max Pay
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Max_Pay__c}" 
required="true"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

</apex:pageBlockSection>


<apex:pageBlockSection title="Education and Skills" columns="3">


<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >   

    Educational Requirements
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Educational_Requirements__c}" 
required="true"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

    Skills Required        
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Skills_Required__c}" required="false"/>

</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

    Apex
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Apex__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    C#
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.C_sharp__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    Java
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.Java__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    JavaScript
    <apex:inputField value="{!Position__c.JavaScript__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

<apex:selectList value="{!selected}" multiselect="true">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!websites}"/>
</apex:selectList>






</apex:pageBlockSection>


</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:Form>
</apex:page>
```

And this is the code from the controller, where I'm attempting to retrieve the selected values and sort through to determine if the website was selected:

```
    public class PositionExtension {

public Position__c pos{get; set;}
public List<Employment_Website__c> employ{get;set;}
Public List<Job_Posting__c> joblist = new List<Job_Posting__c>();
Public Set<String> selected{get;set;}

public PositionExtension (ApexPages.StandardController controller){

    pos = (Position__c)Controller.getRecord();

}

//List<Job_Posting__c> postings = [SELECT Id, Employment_Website__c FROM Job_Posting__c WHERE Position__c = :pos.Id];

public List<Employment_Website__c> website{

    get{return [SELECT Id, Name, web_address__c FROM Employment_Website__c];}
    set{website = value;}

}

public List<SelectOption> getWebsites(){

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    for (Employment_Website__c web : website){


        options.add(new SelectOption(web.Id, web.name));

    }

    return options;
}

public Set<String> updateSelected(){

    return selected;
}

public PageReference save(){

    //List<Job_Posting__c> postings = [SELECT Id, Employment_Website__c FROM Job_Posting__c WHERE Position__c = :pos.Id];

    upsert pos;

    for(Employment_Website__c web : website){
        system.debug(selected);
        if(selected.contains(web.Id)){
            Job_Posting__c posting = new Job_Posting__c();
            posting.Employment_Website__c = web.Id;
            posting.Position__c = pos.Id;
            joblist.add(posting);
        }
    }

    upsert joblist;


    PageReference acctPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(pos).view();
    acctPage.setRedirect(true);
    return acctPage;

}
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get the selected values back into the controller to create a job posting? Let me know if I should post more of my Visualforce code. Thanks!

Comment: In `system.debug(selected);` is selected null?

Comment: No, selected is {get; set;}

Comment: It should be the list of values that the user selects in the list of websites

Comment: Right.. so it is null, I'm also guessing your missing code for when you call save() from your vf page.  Move `system.debug(selected);` outside of the for loop

Comment: Ok I didn't know. I moved the system.debug(selected) outside of the for loop and the problem persists

Comment: That wouldn't cause the problem, where is your button for save in the vf page

Comment: It's at the top of my code. I'll include all of my Visualforce code

Comment: All of my VF code is there

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert data type for selected.

Current :
Public Set selected{get;set;}

Updated
Public **List** selected{get;set;}